# nginx.service - The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server

Tags: http, nginx, centos, centos7, flarum

● nginx.service - The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2022-09-16 13:01:56 +03; 22s ago
Process: 51304 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Process: 51302 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 51300 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/rm -f /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

```
Sep 16 13:01:54 server.oyunculab.com nginx[51304]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0...)
Sep 16 13:01:54 server.oyunculab.com nginx[51304]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0...)
Sep 16 13:01:55 server.oyunculab.com nginx[51304]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0...)
Sep 16 13:01:55 server.oyunculab.com nginx[51304]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0...)
Sep 16 13:01:56 server.oyunculab.com nginx[51304]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0...)
Sep 16 13:01:56 server.oyunculab.com nginx[51304]: nginx: [emerg] still could n...)
Sep 16 13:01:56 server.oyunculab.com systemd[1]: nginx.service: control process...1
Sep 16 13:01:56 server.oyunculab.com systemd[1]: Failed to start The nginx HTTP....
Sep 16 13:01:56 server.oyunculab.com systemd[1]: Unit nginx.service entered fai....
Sep 16 13:01:56 server.oyunculab.com systemd[1]: nginx.service failed.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Comment: Please add full output of `systemctl status nginx -l` and also `journalctl -f -u nginx`